# Is there anyway to send to database through github.io sites?

Tags: database, scripting, github-pages

I may be incorrect because the questions are from a long time ago, but it seems that github.io sites do not allow dynamic content. What I mean is I don't think I can post a php or python script to post to a database from a github.io site.

Does this mean there is no way to send registration information to a database from one of these sites?

If there is a way to run scripts that would be helpful as well. Thanks in advance.

Comment: No you cannot run script on github pages servers. But you can use scripts client side. See @geoom answer.

Answer (score 2):

what about [firebase](https://www.firebase.com/) ? , you can use it as a Realtime data storage, user authentication, static hosting, and more. it has a javascript library that allows you to access to Firebase's authentication and database features from your static site on Github pages.

Take a look at tutorial [here](https://www.firebase.com/tutorial/#gettingstarted).

Comment: Thank you this looks to be a great workaround! However, if there is something allowing scripts it would be a better answer